# Variance Covariance Matrix from vector to matrix format

Tags: r, statistics

I have what supposed to be a variance covariance matrix NxN  in a form of two vectors. 
One vector contains values of variances and the other the covariances.
I've made an example with a simplified number of N to illustrate. 
The real problem is a 1500x1500 matrix:

What I have:

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    N = 4
    names <- c("a","b","c","d")

     matrix_var_cov <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = N, ncol = N) %>% 
    `colnames<-`(.,names) %>% `rownames<-`(.,names)

    variance <- as.data.frame(c("aa","bb","cc","dd")) %>% `colnames<- 
    `(.,"Covariance")

    covariance <- as.data.frame(c("ab","ac","bc","ad","bd","cd")) %>% 
    `colnames<-`(.,"Variance")
```

As you can notice from the covariance dataframe is that the order is given by column.
I have from column B: AB, 
from column C: AC and BC, 
from column D: AD, BD and CD and so on.

There are a couple of ways to interpretate what I just said above, this one is from my point of view.

What I need as output:

```r
output <- data.frame(
  c("aa","ab","ac","ad"),
  c("ab","bb","bc","bd"),
  c("ac","cb","cc","cd"),
  c("ad","bd","cd","dd")) %>% 
   `colnames<-`(.,names) %>% `rownames<-`(.,names)
```

So what i really need is to take the DF with the information of variance and covariance. 
Is there any smart way to do this? 
And no, the source from information cannot be changed.

Comment: You say that you have a *"variance covariance matrix NxN in a form of two vectors"*, however your sample data for the variance and covariance are two `data.frame`s (with a single column). And as a minor comment: This is a fairly abstruse way to construct sample data. For example, why not just `variance <- data.frame(Covariance = c("aa","bb","cc","dd"))`? Personally I don't think the pipes help to make it more readable. Lastly, your `variance` `data.frame` contains a `Covariance` column, and your `covariance` `data.frame` a `Variance` column. Is that a typo?

Comment: There also seems to be a typo in your expected `output` where you have two different entries `"bc"` and `"cb"`, whereas your `covariance` `data.frame` only contains a `"bc"` entry.

Comment: Down vote from me (-1) for posting a question and not responding to comments for more than 3 days. This is not how SO works. You're asking others to help *you* with *your* problem for free. Its should be common courtesy to "hang around" to clarify on issues/comments pertaining to the question you posted.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to specify the diagonal and off-diagonal elements directly. `gdata` offer functions `upperTriangle` and `lowerTriangle` where we can give data by row (base R's `lower.tri` and `upper.tri` give entries "by column").

```
# Sample data
mat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = N, ncol = N, dim = list(names, names))
variance <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd")
covariance <- c("ab","ac","bc","ad","bd","cd")

library(gdata)
diag(mat) <- variance
lowerTriangle(mat, byrow = T) <- covariance
upperTriangle(mat, byrow = T) <- lowerTriangle(mat)
mat
#    a    b    c    d
#a "aa" "ab" "ac" "ad"
#b "ab" "bb" "bc" "bd"
#c "ac" "bc" "cc" "cd"
#d "ad" "bd" "cd" "dd"
```

We can achieve the same in base R by (1) filling the upper triangular matrix, (2) transposing the matrix resulting in the proper order of entries of the lower triangular matrix, and (3) finally filling the upper triangular matrix.

```
# Sample data
mat <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = N, ncol = N, dim = list(names, names))
variance <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd")
covariance <- c("ab","ac","bc","ad","bd","cd")

diag(mat) <- variance
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- covariance
mat <- t(mat)
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- covariance
mat
#    a    b    c    d
#a "aa" "ab" "ac" "ad"
#b "ab" "bb" "bc" "bd"
#c "ac" "bc" "cc" "cd"
#d "ad" "bd" "cd" "dd"
```

Note that there seems to be a typo in your expected output, where it gives a `"cb"` entry that is not present in your covariance vector.